# Entity framework with IN Clause in Repository Pattern

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.1

I looking for some help on how to implement `IN` clause in the repository pattern. Rather than making single call for each and every record, I will have set of IDs, pass on this IDs to Context to get entities which satisfies the condition using Repository Pattern with EF.

I knew we can have something like this:

```
context.Students.Where( x => StudentIDs.contains(x.ID))
```

How to implement same in the repository layer or pattern with single call to DB?

Comment: Just expose the IQueryable.

Comment: And how does this context.Students.Where( x => StudentIDs.contains(x.ID)) conflict with Repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If you really are a purist, yes you should abstract the `DbContext` entirely as you seem to imply.

I'm not sure I completely understand the issue, but something like that should do the job:

```
namespace EFRepo
{
    class Student
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

    class SchoolRepository
    {
        private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();

        public Student Add(string name)
        {
            Student student = new Student { Name = name };

            context.Students.Add(student);

            context.SaveChanges();

            return student;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentsByIds(IEnumerable<long> ids)
        {
            return context.Students.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SchoolRepository repo = new SchoolRepository();

            repo.Add("Bully");
            repo.Add("Crawler");
            repo.Add("Tart");

            foreach (Student s in repo.GetStudentsByIds(new[] { 1L, 3 }))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```